# What did I do wrong in asking my question?

Tags: support

I asked the following question:
[How can I "move" Windows Media Player from my Windows 7 laptop to my Windows 8.1 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135396/how-can-i-move-windows-media-player-from-my-windows-7-laptop-to-my-windows-8-1)

I looked at the help centre, and I had thought that this question fits. It's a question about computer software, about a specific problem that I am facing, that is answerable and is not subjective.

I received another downvote, making three, but no one has left a comment about what is wrong with my question. Can someone please review my question and tell me what I did wrong? I am worried about getting my reputation so low that I get banned from Superuser.

Comment: "VLC doesn't happen to play the DVD properly;" - You should have expanded this statement.  In any event, its not possible to port the WMP from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1.  You can upgrade to Windows 8.1 Media Center to gain that functionality with WMP though.  That is the reason I casted my voted, its not researched well, because there is an alternative to using VLC and that's WMP on `Windows 8.1 Media Center` there is even a Windows Store version of the player also.

Comment: @Ramhound, so if I understand correctly, the expectation is that a person will do a lot of research before writing a post? (I in fact did find out, in the googling I did, that I could pay money to get DVD functionality in Windows 8.1, but I didn't want to pay, and that's why I wrote the post. If I had mentioned this, would the post have still been deserving a downvote?).

Comment: @sylph - I have no idea.  I think trying to predict what could have been, if you had made it known,  you knew about `Windows 8.1 w/Media Center` is sort of non-productive.

Comment: Don't worry about losing rep - the downvotes are not aimed at you personally they are aimed at the question (which isn't overly clear)! I admit, I don't like the voting system here on SE, I think it's heavily flawed and people should leave comments but...! Personally, I don't care about the votes and I suggest you don't either, asking on meta (as you have) is the best way to go! I don't think you'll get banned either for that, as long as you don't keep asking questions which get heavily down-voted. I think Ramhound has pretty much answered it for you in his first comment on this post :)